# how to avoid for loop to append dictionary values in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, append

I have this dictionary :

```
Dict = {
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : 3
}
```

And these two lists :

```
List1 = ["a","c"]
List2 = [0]
```

Is there a more efficient way to append to List2 the corresponding values of List1 through Dict than the following way? :

```
for e in List1:
    List2.append(Dict[e])
```

Result :

```
[0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: You can get the values from Dict:   dict.values(). Its going to return all values in a list

Comment: ```list2.extend(Dict[e] for e in List1)``` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not any more efficient in terms of running time, but more efficient in terms of code written:

```
List2.extend(Dict[e] for e in List1)
```

If you are interested in code golf,

```
List2.extend(map(Dict.get, List1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know what is the most efficient in terms of running time between both solutions ?

Comment: For this small example, the second one appears to be about 30% faster, but in absolute terms the different is negligible (601 ns vs 474 ns), and this could change depending on the sizes of `List1` and `Dict`. Like any performance measurements, wait until you suspect there is a *need* for something to be faster before worrying whether it *can* be faster.